# Support UNION ALL function in BigQuery SQL Issue

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union-all, correlated-subquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

## How can i make this query run on GCP big query without error:

'Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.'

---

Do you guys have any ideia how can i resolve this conflict?

```
 Select
  x.subject_id as PatientId
  ,sum(x.BPS) as sbp
  ,sum(x.RR) as rr
  ,sum(x.sepsis) as sepsis
From (
  Select
    c.subject_id
    ,(
    Select  (Case
      WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) <= 90 THEN 3
            WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) >= 91 AND cast(c2.value as numeric) <= 100 THEN 2
            WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) >= 101 AND cast(c2.value as numeric) < 110 THEN 1
            WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) >= 111 AND cast(c2.value as numeric) < 219 THEN 0
      WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) >= 220 THEN 3
      else 0
         End)
    From    chartevents c2
    Where   c2.subject_id = c.subject_id
        and c2.itemid = c.itemid
        limit 1
    ) as BPS
    ,0 as RR
  ,0 as sepsis
  From
    chartevents c
  Where
    c.itemid = 220050
  Group by
    c.subject_id
    ,c.itemid
  Union all
  Select
    c.subject_id
    ,0 as BPS
    ,(Select  (Case
      WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) <= 8 THEN 3
            WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) >= 9 AND cast(c2.value as numeric) <= 11 THEN 1
            WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) >= 12 AND cast(c2.value as numeric) <= 20 THEN 0
            WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) >= 21 AND cast(c2.value as numeric) <= 24 THEN 2
            WHEN cast(c2.value as numeric) >= 25 THEN 3
      else 0
         End)
    From    chartevents c2
    Where   c2.subject_id = c.subject_id
        and c2.itemid = c.itemid
       limit 1
   ) as RR
  ,0 as sepsis
  From
    chartevents c
  Where
    c.itemid = 220210
  Group by
    c.subject_id
    ,c.itemid
  Union all
    Select
        c.subject_id
        ,0 as BPS
        ,0 as RR
      ,(case when exists (
                      Select  1
                      From    diagnoses_icd d
                      Where   d.subject_id = c.subject_id
                              and d.icd9_code like '%99591%'
                      )
              then 1
              else 0
        end) as sepsis
      From
        chartevents c
      Where
        c.itemid = 228334
      Group by
        c.subject_id
        ,c.itemid
) x
Group by
   x.subject_id
   limit 5
;
```

> Desired output:

| PatientId | sbp | rr | sepsis|

|     1     |  0  |  0 |   0   |
|     2     |  2  |  3 |   1   |

> 

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question easier to follow.

Comment: In addition to what GMB says, I would also strongly suggest simplifying the query.

Comment: I Added more information.
How can I simplify this query and bring the same results. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @ViniciusFerreira . . . For instance, you probably don't need all the columns to generate the error.   The error is probably generated in just one of the subqueries of the `union all`.  There are two ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because of `chartevents c2` subqueries. Try to convert them to [ARRAY_AGG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) construction.

This will generate error:

```
SELECT
  c.subject_id,
  (
      SELECT c2.value * 2
      FROM chartevents c2
      WHERE c2.subject_id = c.subject_id
        AND c2.itemid = c.itemid
      LIMIT 1
  ) as BPS
FROM
  chartevents c
```

This will work:

```
SELECT
  c.subject_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(c2.value * 2 LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS BPS
FROM chartevents AS c
JOIN chartevents AS c2
ON c2.subject_id = c.subject_id
  AND c2.itemid = c.itemid
```